# "... gehört erschossen" Ursprung der Redewendung

Tags: phrase

Insb. wenn mich schlechte Usability von einem Tool/Webseite sehr nervt kommt mir die Redewendung 'Wer auch immer X gemacht hat gehört erschossen." über die Lippen, von der ich nicht weiß wo ich sie aufgegriffen habe. Ich bin immer der Überzeugung gewesen, dass dies eine allgemeine Redewendung ist. Die Redewendung ist zugegeben etwas hart wenn man mit dieser nicht vertraut ist und diese ggf. mit einer Drohung missversteht. Entsprechend kam mir die Frage: **Ist dies eine verbreitete oder (sehr) regionale Redewendung?**

Wenn es sehr regional ist, wäre eine Region im Rheinland/Ruhrpott am wahrscheinlichsten, aber Google hat mir hier nicht weiter geholfen.

Comment: Ich kenne die Redensart in dieser und in anderen Formen, die in Verletzung oder Tod des "Schuldigen" enden.

Comment: Kann gut sein, dass es eine (lokale) Abwandlung ist. Wenn du eine Quelle für eine ausreichend ähnliche Variation findest wäre dies auch ein Accept.

Comment: Ich habe Zweifel daran, dass man hier von einer festen "Redewendung" sprechen kann. Weder die Struktur scheint konstant zu sein (ich kenne sowohl " ... gehört erschossen" als auch "... sollte man erschießen", und es gibt ein weites Feld von Variationen à la "... würde es verdienen, dass mit ihm X passiert", "... für den wäre X noch gnädig" usw.), noch der Inhalt ("... gehört erschossen", "... gehört ausgepeitscht", "... gehört dazu gezwungen, es selber zu benutzen" etc., jeweils auch mit den zuvor genannten Strukturvarianten).

Comment: I agree to @O.R.Mapper. And since I wouldn't consider this a "Redewendung" nor a coloquial term, I'd be careful with using it. It might be interpreted literally and therefore considered a severe threat.

Comment: @PMF: Wait a moment, while I do not consider this a "Redewendung", a fixed expression or set term of any kind, the *general idea* to express one's dissatisfaction about or anger at another party (usually someone whose - probably somewhat reasonable - decision nonetheless makes things more cumbersome or inconvenient for you) along the lines of "<accused party> should be subjected to <insert whatever uncomfortable thing you wish to happen to them>" is definitely widely known and a very usual thing to invoke in casual conversation. Of course, do not use in contexts where your every word ...

Comment: ... might be used against you or where you are expected to show a great amount of political correctness.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In coloquial speech, or maybe with your friends in the pub, I agree. But if you publicly (or in the internet) say something like "XY sollte wegen seiner Coronapolitik erschossen werden", I guess you'd be in trouble.

Comment: @PMF: Indeed, though this makes me recognize one more constant of the described pattern: The target person is usually someone anonymous, defined solely by the fact of having caused the inconvenience. In that respect, the example by the OP, "Wer auch immer X gemacht hat ..." (and only when it is really unclear who that concrete person might be), is very typical. You do not want any harm to happen to a real person, you want to express the degree of annoyment you are feeling.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ok, I agree to this. I have the feeling that some people don't know the difference, though (or maybe even don't care about the difference).

Comment: Ich interessiere mich dafür, warum diese Frage so gestellt wurde. Hast Du selbst den Spruch mal vor Dich hingemurmelt und bist damit ins Fettnäpfchen getreten, weil der Urheber der schändlichen Programmierung das mitbekommen hat? Oder hat jemand mal den Spruch von Dir kommentiert und gesagt, das sei wohl doch ein bisschen heftig? Geht's eher darum, wie 'erlaubt' oder 'unerlaubt' so eine Bemerkung ist? Ich komm drauf, weil im Ruhrgebiet rustikalere Ausdrucksweisen vielleicht wirklich etwas verbreiteter sind und man damit hier weniger auffallen mag als anderswo in Deutschland. Geht's um sowas?

Answer (score 5):

[DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=geh%C3%B6rt%20erschossen&corpus=public&date-start=1465&date-end=2018&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=50) liefern immerhin 16 Treffer, auch wenn einige historisch sein mögen.

An eine regionale Besonderheit glaube ich nicht (siehe überregionale Zeitungen), besonders häufig ist die Wendung wegen der Drastik aber sicher nicht - solche Steilvorlagen gibt man seinen Gegnern nicht gern.

Aufgrund des bedeutungsgleichen *gehört an die Wand gestellt* (nämlich vor ein Erschießungskommando), hätte ich auf martialisch-militärische Herkunft getippt. Das wird durch [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erschie%C3%9Fung#Erschie%C3%9Fung_durch_Peloton) bestätigt, wo sowohl *an die Wand stellen* als *Soldatensprache* bezeichnet wird, als auch durch den militärischen Bezug von *Standrecht* (wie in *standrechtlich erschießen*).

Comment: Es klingt martialisch, was aber nicht eine militärische Herkunft beweist. Ich sehe das Erschießen eher als eine Hinrichtungsmethode, die es auch außerhalb militärischer Strukturen (Todesstrafe!) gab und gibt. Vgl. [hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erschie%C3%9Fung). In den DWDS-Beispielen fällt auf, dass  mehrere Zitate aus anderen Sprachen stammen. Die Verwendung dürfte also international sein.

Answer (score 2):

For me, **gehören + Partizip Perfekt** is not a 'Redewendung' but a grammatical structure. *Gehören + Partizip 2* means *must / should be + past participle*. In German, it is a "*Passiv-Ersatzform*" (substitute).

Examples:

> Das Blasphemiegesetz gehört nicht nur abgemildert, sondern abgeschafft.  = *The blasphemy law should not just be toned down, but abolished.*
>
> Rauchen in der Öffentlichkeit gehört verboten! = *Smoking in public places should be banned.*
>
> Dieses Gesetz gehört überarbeitet. = *The law should be revised.*
>
> Der Mann gehört eingesperrt. = That man needs locking up.

You can**not** transform any German *must-passive* into *gehören + Partizip 2*; theoretically, you can do that, but in most cases it would sound strange. As you may have noticed, the *gehören-Passiv* is used to express the speaker's non-negotiable (ultimate) conviction of what should be done. You will find it quite often in legal contexts.

I give a link to further examples from [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%40geh%C3%B6rt%20%24p%3DVVPP&corpus=public&date-start=1465&date-end=2018&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=max&sort=date_desc&limit=50&p=1).

Members of the educated classes are likely to reject the construction as *no good German*. It is in fact colloquial.

As only a few past participles occur within a *gehören-Passiv*, it may seem to be a 'Redewendung', which is, I think, neither correct nor false. One may regard '*erschossen gehören*' as an idiom, but one should be aware of the fact that there is more than '*erschossen*' that can be combined with *gehören*.

Comment: M.E. bezog sich die Frage nicht auf die allgemeine Form "gehört [Partizip Perfekt]", sondern auf die Verwendung von **erschossen**.

Comment: Nein, es wurde die "Redewendung" _gehört erschossen_ angefragt, denn die Bedeutung von _erschossen_ ist da nicht das Problem, sondern seine unernste bzw. übertreibende Verwendung in dieser Struktur. Gemeint ist jedenfalls: _Den sollte man erschießen!_ Für mich ist das lediglich ein unüberlegter Spruch, kein Idiom, und für das _abmurksen_ könnte man alles Mögliche einsetzen, siehe Guidots Antwort: _an die Wand stellen_ (Idiom, echt zu krass für die Situation), _auf den Mond schießen_ (Idiom), _nicht frei herumlaufen lassen_ (idiomartig) usw. ...

Comment: Eingeleitet wird so etwas oft mit _Wer das verbrochen hat_ oder _Der/Den Kerl, der diesen Mist verzapft hat (der gehört ... / den sollte man)_  Mir war es wichtig, darauf hinzuweisen, dass hier die Bezeichnung "Redewendung / Redensart" suboptimal ist, da es sich um eine grammatikalisierte Struktur von 'gehören' handelt. Ein _gehören-Passiv_ ist für sich genommen keine Redewendung, kann aber redewendungsartig benutzt werden.

Comment: Natürlich bezieht sich die Frage nicht auf Wort "erschossen" als solches, sondern auf die Verwendung in der Kombination "der gehört erschossen". Die Frage lautet im Originaltext: "Ist dies eine verbreitete oder (sehr) regionale Redewendung?" Dazu finde ich Deiner Antwort nichts.

Comment: Doch!: Meine Antwort ist: Es ist weder eine verbreitete noch eine regionale Redewendung, denn es ist gar keine Redewendung. Eine Redewendung wäre es, wenn nur die Kombination "gehört erschossen" vorkommen würde, es gibt jedoch auch _gehört eingesperrt, gehört abgeschafft, gehört bestraft, gehört verboten, gehört weggeklickt_, leider sogar von asozialen Elementen auch _gehört vergast_ usw. usw. Worauf willst du überhaupt hinaus? Soll das eine Beweisführung werden, dass meine Antwort am Thema vorbei ist? Wozu wäre das gut? Soll ich's wieder löschen?

Comment: Ich sehe keinen Grund, die Antwort zu löschen. Aber es ist doch klar (zumindest für mich), dass der Fragesteller wissen wollte, ob der Satz mit Schema "Wer [...] getan hat, gehört erschossen"  allgemein oder nur regional (z.B. im Rheinland/Ruhrgebiet) verwendet wird. Und für mich lautet die Antwort (obwohl ich es nicht  durch Statistiken beweisen kann): Es ist im ganzen deutschen Sprachaum verbreitet.

Comment: Ich hatte auch darüber nachgedacht, kann dazu aber keine belegbare Auskunft geben und frage mich eher, warum user46957 die Frage gestellt hat, denn zu was nützt jemandem eine solche Auskunft? Ich werd' ihn dazu direkt fragen.